# What is the best solution for caching in clustered Node Js application?

Tags: express, node-cluster

I used  [cluster-node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cluster-node-cache) with following code.

```
var obj = { my: "Special", variable: 42 };
        cache.set("myKey", obj).then(function(result) {
                console.log(result.err);
                console.log(result.success);

                cache.get("myKey").then(function(result2) {
                    console.log(result2.err);
                    console.log(result2.success);
                });

        });
```

This resulted in following output

```
null
true
null
undefined
```

Certainly, with this result, [cluster-node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cluster-node-cache) is not a solution for caching requirement with cluster.
  Please suggest best solution and why that solution is best?

Comment: The code as written doesn't even make sense; you're asking for `result2.success` which *is* `undefined`. According to the node-cache docs, the result of a `get` is an object with `err` and `value` keys. If nothing else, I'd at least recommend following the actual API before deciding whether or not it works for you.

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton I have followed example code form cluster-node-cache github page.  I know there should be  err object in callback but example in github page of library says other way.

Comment: Look at the docs for get: https://github.com/lvx3/cluster-cache/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton please have look over this example ..  myCache.get(["keyA", "keyB"]).then(function(results) {
  if(results.err) {
    console.log(results.err);
  } else {
    console.log(results.value);
  }
});    ...

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton please have look over this example code from link given by you( on Retrieve a key (GET): heading)  ......  eyCache.get("myKey").then(function(results) {
  if(results.err) {
    console.log(results.err);
  } else {
    console.log(results.value.myKey);
  }
});   ...  there is no err object here!! .. I am great full for your time.

Comment: Correct, because you're not getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

Since memory data is not shared among different processes, cluster cache does not seems to solve problem of caching in clustered nodejs application.

I solved this caching  issue with redis server. redis server have good performance and it can be clustered further(for bigger applications)